# @ModelAttribute always null after Ajax Post Request

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, modelattribute

iam using mvc spring for a form.
All works fine, but i get always

> @ModelAttribute EncondingModel encodingTABnet

as null.
When i have a look at the Ajax Call

> $('#encoding_form').serialize()

it has that value:

> "password=asdfasdf&key=asdfasdfasdfasdfasdf"

But at my controller the Model is always null.
Can anybody help me finding my problem?

Form.jsp:

```
<form:form id="encoding_form" modelAttribute="encodingTABnet" commandName="encodingTABnet" name="form-encoding-do">
    <form:input cssClass="password" type="text" placeholder="Passwort Plain" path="password"/>
    <form:input cssClass="key" type="text" placeholder="Secret Key" path="key"/>
    <br>
    <button type="button" class="btn" onclick="${ns}calculateForm()"><i class="tab-icon tab-icon-ok">Start encoding</i></button>

    <div class="error-message"></div>
</form:form>
```

View.jsp

```
<portlet:actionURL var="calculatePasswordAjaxURL" windowState="EXCLUSIVE">
   <portlet:param name="action" value="calculateForm"/>
</portlet:actionURL>

<script> 
 function ${ns}calculateForm() {
    $.post("${calculatePasswordAjaxURL}", $('#encoding_form').serialize(), function (data) {
        container.html(data);
    });

 }
</script>
```

Controller:

```
@RenderMapping(params = "action=showForm")
public String showFormView(Model model, RenderRequest request, RenderResponse response) throws Exception {

    return ENCODING_FORM;
}

@ActionMapping(params = "action=showForm")
public void showForm(ActionRequest request, ActionResponse response, Model model) throws Throwable {

    final EncodingModel encoding = new EncodingModel();
    model.addAttribute("encodingTABnet", encoding);

    response.setRenderParameter("action", "showForm");
}

@ActionMapping(params = "action=calculateForm")
public void calculatePassword(@ModelAttribute EncodingModel encodingTABnet, BindingResult result,
                        ActionRequest actionRequest, ActionResponse actionResponse,
                        Model model, SessionStatus status) {

    allstuff =  new AllStuff();
    allstuff.setKey(encodingTABnet.getKey());
    allstuff.setPassword(encodingTABnet.getPassword());
    allstuff.setEncode(aes.encrypt(encodingTABnet.getPassword(), encodingTABnet.getKey()));

    status.setComplete();

    actionResponse.setRenderParameter("action", "showContent");
}
```

Class:

```
public class EncodingModel   {


private String password;
private String key;

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}
public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
public String getKey() {
    return key;
}
public void setKey(String key) {
    this.key = key;
}
```

}

Comment: The Javadoc for `@ModelAttribute`states: "Supported for controller classes with @RequestMapping methods." whereas you are using `@ActionMapping`

Comment: Thanks, but that state can be used also at Action Mapping. There are many examples at the web. Problem is, that i can not find my issue.

Comment: Try to add the name of your model as a parameter of your annotation like this : `@ModelAttribue("encodingTABnet")`

Comment: I thought that `@ModelAttribute` is only used for simple form submissions. For data submitted by AJAX it should be marked by `@RequestBody` annotation. Could you test it?

Comment: Tested both, nothing changed. Its's strange, because i have other portlets with the same functions like that, which are working well.

Comment: @Nscd why are you using `modelAttribute` and `commandName` on same form use either `modelAttribute` or `commandName` and then check that